# execvp ("/usr/bin/bc", arg, env)

Tags: c, exec, bc

I have doubts about how to throw in C an execv of bc. How should the parameters be passed (for example: 3, +, 2)? Would it be for a pipe? Or by the argv despite being int? And, if this exec was thrown by the child, would the parent collect that value with a read from the pipe?
Thank you!

Comment: Since `bc` takes file names as arguments, you'll either have to arrange for `3 + 2` to be sent to its standard input (pipe?) or write `3 + 2` to a file and tell `bc` to process the file (and remove the file later).  The `execvp()` system call takes just two arguments, normally `execvp(argv[0], argv)` for some null-terminated vector of strings.  The value of `argv[0]` will be `bc` — if you specify the path, there's no point in using `execvp()` instead of `execv()`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I put this:
sprintf(str1, "%d", num1);
  sprintf(strop, "%d", operando);
  sprintf(str2, "%d", num2);
  strcat(str, str1);
  strcat(str, strop);
  strcat(str, str2);
  char *argumentos[] = {"bc", str};
  execvp("/usr/bin/bc", argumentos);
Would it? Before I tried to pass through a pipe the values ​​3 + 2, I also tried to create an auxiliary file where I wrote 3 + 2 and passed that file to the exec of bc .... In no case I have managed to recover the value of the result in the parent. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @ssuarez: on the right-hand side of this page, you should see a section labeled **"Related"**, and there you will probably find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995172/writing-a-term-to-bc-via-pipes-in-c). Check out the accepted answer. It's always good to look at related questions :)

Comment: I had already looked at that related question, but I get an error "(standard_in) 1: read() in flex scanner failed"

Comment: Please add your code to the question as an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There are almost endless ways you could be mishandling the process, and we can't guess which ones you've chosen — you're more inventive than we can possibly be.

Comment: This question has been superseded, I think, by [My program stops after doing the exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610666/my-program-stops-after-doing-the-exec).  I think it unlikely that this question will be further improved.

Answer (score 0):

The arg should be a string.  Same as if the arguments had been typed in a terminal.  If you have several integer arguments, you must convert them to a string representation first.  As for `env`, you can pass the `env` you got in `main()`, or an empty environment as in:

```
char *env[] = { NULL };
```

Comment: The argument to `bc` is a filename, not an expression.

Comment: For some reason, the OP mentions passing "3, +, 2".

Comment: If the OP knew how to do what they want to do, they wouldn't be asking a question here. :) `execvp` doesn't take an `env` argument either; you need `execvpe` if you want to pass an environment, but in this case there is not much need.